# Examples of solutions of an ODE with this property

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ be a $C^1$ class function and suppose that $\varphi(t)$ defined in $\mathbb R$ is a solution of $x'=f(t,x)$, $x(t_0)=x_0$.

I've been thinking if there is such function such that there are points $t_0, t_1$ with $\varphi'(t_1)$ and $\varphi'(t_0)$ linearly independent (see picture below).

I found in a book the following function which can help us to solve this question:

$f:\mathbb R\times\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$, given by $f(t,(x,y))=(t\cos t+\sin t,t^2\cos t+2t \sin t)$ with initial conditions $(x(0),y(0))=(0,0)$. I'm analyzing $\varphi( \pi), \varphi( 2\pi), \varphi'( \pi), \varphi'( 2\pi)$.

Unfortunately, due my lack of experience in this subject, I have still problems to prove that this point have the properties I mentioned above.

[image]

I really need help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Any smooth parametric curve $\varphi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^n$ is a solution of the ODE of the kind you described. Just let $f(t,x)=\varphi'(t)$: the equation $x'=f(t,x)$ obviously holds for $x=\varphi(t)$.

In particular, you can choose $\varphi(t)=(t+\cos 2t,\sin t)$ which [crosses itself infinitely many times](http://fooplot.com/plot/kwbxcu53e9).

If your ODE was time-independent, i.e., $x'=f(x)$, then self-intersections are impossible, since the tangent vector is determined by the location.

Comment: How can we prove that the tangent in the intersection are LI?